# which one is better in terms of performance, the early binding or late binding in Delphi COM objects

Tags: delphi, com

In delphi, if you want to create COM object, you can do it in two ways,

the first one is early binding, for example,

```
uses
  MSScriptControl_TLB; // MS Script Control

var
  obj: IScriptControl;
begin
  obj := CreateOleObject('ScriptControl') as IScriptControl;
  .. 
  ..
  obj.ExecuteStatement('Msgbox 1') 
end;
```

Or, you can do it as following (late binding)

```
var
  obj: OleVariant;

begin
  obj := CreateOleObject('ScriptControl') ;
  obj.ExecuteStatement('Msgbox 1');
end;
```

which one is better in terms of performance?

Comment: Early or late binding doesn't change whether or not elevation is required. Impossible to answer "which is better". Sometimes early bind better, other times late bind better.

Comment: strange, but the fact is I change from second to the first approach, the error disappears.

Comment: and it was all working on win7. anyway, my main question is which one is better in terms of performance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Which one is better in terms of performance?

Early bound is quicker than late bound. Late bound method dispatch involves the following:

1. Looking up the entry point from the name.
2. Assembling the parameters to be passed to the method, and performing any necessary type conversions.
3. Calling the function.
4. Unmarshalling any out parameters and the return value.

Many of these steps are not present at all for early bound dispatch.

Of course, if the function does anything significant at all, the performance different during method dispatch may well not be detectable.

Comment: It would be better if you could edit the question simply to ask "which one is better in terms of performance?" As it stands, the question as originally asked is not a good fit for SO. But the question that I answered is fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Not sure if you're familiar enough with C++Builder to answer this related q of mine which is still awaiting a good answer...? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670175/late-binding-com-objects-with-cbuilder

Comment: @Roddy Sorry, I don't use C++Builder

Comment: Late bound method calls do not push parameter values onto the stack. Early bound calls do. Late bound parameters are stored in a Variant array instead, and then the array is passed to the method. The caller may, but does not need to, retrieve the parameters and types ahead of time, the compiler can infer them statically from the code, but the called method will fail if it detects a mismatch, and will report back what the actual mismatch is.