# how to speed up accessing the Fields collection in Word by using Delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-word

I need change fields's content,but this way is take too much time,how can i do? Anyone can help me

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  WordApp, WordDocument, Field: OleVariant;
  I: Integer;
begin
  WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  try
    WordDocument := WordApp.Documents.Open('C:\MyDoc.doc');
    if WordDocument.Fields.Count >= 1 then 
      for I := 1 to WordDocument.Fields.Count do
      begin
        **Field := WordDocument.Fields.Item(I);   // file size:20M，Fields.Count:30, This step takes 3 seconds**
      end;
  finally
    WordApp.Quit;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Does the word app update somehow in the background when you work on the document ? Try to switch off update with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`.

Comment: yes, I have already set up.

Answer (score 1):

Please use early binding as shown here [which one is better in terms of performance, the early binding or late binding in Delphi COM objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383304/which-one-is-better-in-terms-of-performance-the-early-binding-or-late-binding-i)
The performance increase is significant.