# Late-bound call to VB6 interface methods

Tags: c++, interface, com, vb6

In my C++ program I use a COM class which is implemented in a VB6 COM DLL. Let's call this class `CETicketRA`. This class has a property `AppliedPromotion` of type `IPositionPromotion`. `IPositionPromotion` is an interface defined by the same VB6 COM DLL. It has various properties and methods which I try to access from C++.

Given the following code:

```cpp
IDispatch* pETicketRA = NULL;
DISPPARAMS dispParams = {0};
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);
// Left out: some code to set pETicketRA ...

OLECHAR* strAppliedPromotion = L"AppliedPromotion";
DISPID dispIDAppliedPromotion = -1;
HRESULT hr = pETicketRA->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &strAppliedPromotion, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispIDAppliedPromotion);
hr = pETicketRA->Invoke(dispIDAppliedPromotion, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &dispParams, &result, NULL, NULL);
IDispatch* pPromo = NULL;
hr = result.pdispVal->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&pPromo));
VariantClear(&result);
```

Now I try to read the property `Foobar` of `IPositionPromotion`:

```cpp
OLECHAR* strFoobar = L"Foobar";
DISPID dispIDFoobar = -1;
hr = pPromo->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &strFoobar, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispIDFoobar);
```

Unfortunately the last call fails with `DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME`.

Has anyone succeeded to call VB6 interface members from C++ (or C#)?

Comment: In C# you can do it VB6-style with `dynamic`. For C++, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11670175/11683 might help.

Comment: Not sure if the COM regulations are tighter, but usually C++ mangles the names of functions causing dynamic errors when trying to access the object at runtime.  _IF_ that is the case, be sure to `extern "C"` as required.

Comment: @GSerg: I tried dynamic already, it does not work. But I found out something: In the VB6 COM DLL, in the classes that implement `IPositionPromotion`, the methods that implement the `IPositionPromotion` interface usually are declared as `Private`. They are named `IPositionPromotion_Foobar`. If I change them from `Private` to `Public`, I can call `IPositionPromotion_Foobar` on the `pPromo` object.
But this is a quite ugly "solution".

Comment: @TimoKunze They are supposed to private, this is VB6's convention for implementing interfaces and event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB6 uses explicit interface implementation. Methods of implemented interface do not become a part of the implementing object's public interface, and in order to call them you need to explicitly ask for the interface. You can ask `IDispatch` out of that interface later if you wish, but you need to query for the interface first, because `IDispatch` you get from the object itself and `IDispatch` you get from the interface implemented by this object will be different `IDispatch`es.

So when you have:

```vb
' IInterface.cls
Public Sub Method()
End Sub
```

```vb
' Class1.cls
Implements IInterface

Private Sub IInterface_Method()
  MsgBox "!"
End Sub
```

and you want to create an instance of `Class1` and call `Method()`, the following will *not* work:

```vb
' Complile-time error: method not found
Dim c As Class1
Set c = New Class1

c.Method
```

```vb
' Run-time error: Object does not support this property or method
Dim c As Object    ' IDispatch
Set c = New Class1 ' QueryInterface for IDispatch from Class1

c.Method
```

And the following will work:

```vb
Dim c As IInterface
Set c = New Class1

c.Method  ' Early binding
```

```vb
Dim c As IInterface
Set c = New Class1

Dim c_as_idispatch As Object   ' IDispatch
Set c_as_idispatch = c         ' QueryInterface for IDispatch from IInterface

c.Method  ' Late binding
```

Your C++ code is identical to the second non-working example above.

To fix it, first `QueryInterface` for `IPositionPromotion`, then query `IDispatch` off that.

Comment: Got it working with a small adjustment, yeah!
I declared the `IPositionPromotion` interface in C++, derived from `IDispatch`. I used OleView to get the IID of the interface, as the ProgID refers to the CLSID of the coclass. With this combination, I indeed can `QueryInterface` the `result.pdispVal` object for `IPositionPromotion`. Then I indeed can `QueryInterface` this one for `IDispatch`. This object does not know any `Foobar` method, but why should I use `IDispatch` when I can use the `IPositionPromotion` interface? I can use it to call `Foobar` and it works!
Thanks a lot!